# Flair widget prevents me from loading Blogger page

Tags: support, flair, blogger

[Also posted as a [question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/171876/superuser-flair-on-blogger-prevents-me-viewing-page)]

I recently noticed that I can't view my (vestigial) Blogger page due to a pop-up that states:

```
The page at http://stackoverflow.com says:
For security reasons framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.
```

Clicking OK takes me to a 'Page not found' Stackoverflow page with the URL:
`https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/60255.html?theme=default`

This seems to be a problem with the SuperUser **[flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair)** widget code on the Blogger page. Unfortunately I now can't get access to the page to remove it.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?
Any ideas how to remove the code from the Blogger page?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Superuser flair code by disabling Javascript, clicking the Edit link in Blogger, re-enabling Javascript and deleting the code.

The problem seems to have been caused by the flair code containing a broken link:
`http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/60255.html?theme=default` which then forwards to the Stackoverflow 404 page which like all SO pages contains frame busting code which generates the error message and removes the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that that that user ID doesn't exist.  Fix the ID, and the flair should work again.